# C# Function Pointer / Delegate as a Class Field

Tags: c#

I've watched some tutorials and manual pages how to work with delegates but I have still no clue...
I have a class and I need every instance of it to have assigned different method
Let's say something like:

```
public Class Shape{
   public void CalculateArea();
}
```

And then somewhere after declaring `Shape RandomShape;` set `RandomShape.CalculateArea = MethodToCalcThisShapeArea;`

The problem is the exact thing I've just written here doesn't compile because methods in classes must have declared body

So i tried

```
public Class Shape{
   public delegate void CalculateArea();
}
```

But this acts like a static field – I cannot access it from each class instance but only through the class itself
So my last try was

```
public Class Shape{
   public Action CalculateArea;
}
```

Which should be the same (i think) since `Action` is just `delegate void` but in this case I am able to access it from every instance which sounds great but I am still not able to assign it any method because `void cannot be implicitly converted to System.Action`

Comment: You are trying to manually reimplement polymorphism. Just use it directly. Have `abstract class Shape` with `abstract void CalculateArea()` and inherit `RandomShape` from it overriding the `CalculateArea` with proper method. Having that said, you were probably thinking about `public Action CalculateArea(){get;set;}`, to which you could assign things like `RandomShape.CalculateArea = () => 42;`, but then you would at least need to make your actions accept parameters so that they had some data to do the calculations upon, because they won't otherwise have access to the `Shape` instance.

Comment: "But this acts like a static field" - no it doesn't. It acts as a nested type declaration, which is what it is. Using `Action` is correct, but we don't know how you're trying to assign it... my guess is that you're using `CalculateArea = SomeMethod();` (which *invokes* the method) instead of `CalculateArea = SomeMethod;` (which is a method group conversion). Please include a [mcve] instead of pseudo-code.

Comment: *"I am still not able to assign it any method because `void cannot be implicitly converted to System.Action`"* Please show the code that would trigger that error

Answer (score 3):

The line `public delegate void CalculateArea();` declares a *type*, not a per-instance field; you could have, for example:

```cs
public class Shape{
   public delegate void MyDelegateType();
   public MyDelegateType CalculateArea;
}
```

which would declare a type *and* a per-instance field of that type, but a: you'd probably just want to use `Action`, and b: you'd usually use either a property or an event here:

```cs
public class Shape{
   public event Action CalculateArea;
}
```

I also wonder whether an `abstract` method might be more what you're after here:

```cs
public abstract class Shape{
   public abstract void CalculateArea();
}
```